# How to use stars and bars to find number of solutions to this equation?

Tags: combinatorics

How do I apply the method of stars and bars to count the number of solutions to the following equation:

$$a+b=n$$

where $a,b\in\{0,1,2\}$. All possible values of $a,b$ when $n=2$ are $\{0, 2\}$, $\{1, 1\}$, $\{2, 0\}$. When $n=3$, $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$.

If $a,b$ are positive integers, the answer would be ${n+1\choose1}$ but in this problem $a,b$ is limited to a set of values.

Comment: I don't understand what "all possible values of $a,b,c$ in this example are $\{0,2\},\{1,1\},\{2,0\}$" means.   But, whatever it means, there are very, very few cases to consider.  Just write them all down and check which of them satisfy the constraint.

Comment: @Henry sorry I accidentally typed the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, if you just want a solution in non-negative integers then the answer is $\binom{n+1}1$.

If you have an upper-bound on $a,b,c$, then you can't apply the method of stars and bars. In general, the answer will be the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$(1+x+x^2)^2 =1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4. $$
Notice that for $n>4$, the coefficient is zero, which is still the correct answer.

---

More generally, the solution of $a+b=n$ where $a,b\in\{0,\dots,k\}$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $$(1+\cdots+x^k)^2 = \Big(\frac{x(1-x^k)}{1-x}\Big)^2.$$ I can elaborate on this further if it isn't clear why, this is what's called a [generating function](https://brilliant.org/wiki/generating-functions-solving-recurrence-relations/).

Answer (score 1):

Stars and bars may not be the best approach.  Instead look at the generating function:  $$(1\cdot x^0+1\cdot x^1+1\cdot x^2)(1\cdot x^0+1\cdot x^1+1\cdot x^2) \\= 1\cdot x^0+2\cdot x^1+3\cdot x^2+2\cdot x^3+1\cdot x^4$$

and look at the coefficient of $x^n$:

- with $n=2$ you have $3x^2$ so $3$ solutions
- with $n=3$ you have $2x^3$ so $2$ solutions

This is easy to extend to other possible values of $a$ and $b$.